# Functor for GHC.Generics Comp1 (:.:)

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm stuck with Functor instance for composition of other functors in haskell.

```
data Cmps f g x = Cmps {getCmps :: f (g x)} deriving (Eq,Show) 

--
instance (Functor f, Functor g) => Functor (Cmps f g) where
  -- fmap :: (a -> b) -> (Cmps f g) a -> (Cmps f g) b
  fmap = ?
```

In GHC.Generics functor just derived with {-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor          #-}

```
-- | Composition of functors
infixr 7 :.:
newtype (:.:) f (g :: * -> *) (p :: *) = Comp1 { unComp1 :: f (g p) }
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show, Functor, Generic, Generic1)`
```

I can't get some like `fmap h (Cmps f g x) = Cmps f g (h x)` becouse of error
`The constructor ‘Cmps’ should have 1 argument, but has been given 3`, and something like `fmap h (f (g x))` don't work too. How can I get `f, g and x` from `Cmps` type in fmap implementation?

Comment: You are using `Cmps` like it has three fields, but it only has one, of type `f (g x)`. so the left hand side should look like `fmap f (Cmps x) = ...` try again with that in mind. You can also see the instance GHC generates using `DeriveFunctor` with the `-ddump-deriv` option.

Comment: I have moved your solution to an answer proper. For your future questions, note that it is perfectly fine to answer your to own question.

Answer (score 1):

*Consolidating the remarks by Li-yao Xia and orlan as an answer.*

In your `Cmps` definition...

```
data Cmps f g x = Cmps {getCmps :: f (g x)} deriving (Eq,Show)
```

... `f`, `g` and `x` are type variables; they do not stand for fields. `Cmps` has  a single field, of type `f (g x)`. Accordingly, the `fmap` implementation for it should be:

```
instance (Functor f, Functor g) => Functor (Cmps f g) where
  -- fmap :: (a -> b) -> (Cmps f g) a -> (Cmps f g) b
  fmap h (Cmps x) = Cmps (fmap (fmap h) x)
```

If you want to compare that with an equivalent instance in the core libraries which is not derived, have a look at [`Compose`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/src/Data.Functor.Compose.html#line-79) from `Data.Functor.Compose`.